# I have some problems when I work with the NavigationDrawer in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to make an app that has 3 different levels of difficulty and has a NavigationDrawer to change customize the app, for example: Activate dark theme. When I add the navigation drawer, the elements in the window are not moving when the size of the app changes, and it has a weird blank space over the toolbar.

[This is thee window with a default size. Notice the blank space over the toolbar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QUpp.png)

[This happens when I resize the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5tng.png)

[This is the window with the NavigationDrawer toggled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9UfD.png)

[Also, when I reduce the size of the window to the minimum value, this happens with the buttons in the NavigationDrawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT7Ky.png)

This is the kv code, and the Python file contains just an empty class:

```
Screen:
NavigationLayout:
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Screen 1"
            on_release: 
                screen_manager.current = "menu"
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "Screen 2"
            on_release: 
                screen_manager.current = "screen2"
            
    ScreenManager
        id: screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: "menu"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: "50dp"
            
            
                MDToolbar:
                    title: "Toolbar"
                    elevation: 11
                    left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                    
                
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Select your level"
                    halign: "center"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.8}
                    font_style: "H5"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    hight: self.texture_size[1]
                    
                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: "  Advanced  "
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.7}
                    
                    
                    
                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: "Intermediate"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.6}
                    
                    
                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: "       Basic       "
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                    
        Screen:
            name: "screen2"
            MDLabel:
                text: "Screen 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it here, and the dimensioning is working normally.

the white space is because of the "spacing:" 50dp ", change it to 80dp and change you MDLabel to:

```
MDLabel:
    text: "Select your level"

    halign: "center"

    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.8}

    font_style: "H5"
```

Comment: I changed the spacing to 83dp and the blank space disappeared, but when I grab the corner of the screen and resize it, the widgets don't move and the blank space increases as the height of the screen increases.

Comment: main.py:  
`
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(helper)`

Comment: I changed my answer, on how to solve the white space when changing the size